# Pandas - read_table read selected lines

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I work with text files that contain some basic information in the first 6 rows including empty rows. I have to import, process and export the data into another csv. Here is an example of the first 6 rows:

```
Foov7.9 - bar.raw created at 10:45:25 on 10.02.2015:
(empty row)
(empty row)
A B C D
a b c d
(empty row)
```

In pandas I use row 4:

```
A B C D
```

as header for the dataframe:

```
data1 = pd.read_table(dataset1,header = 1, skiprows = (4,5), index_col=None, delimiter=r"\t", engine='python')
```

When writing to_csv after processing the data I now would like to place back the first 6 rows but I already fail when reading the rows. By solely writing the header from row 4 into the csv I would loose all additional information.
How can I read these rows and later put them back into the csv without interfering with the dataframe header?

Comment: Are rows 5 and 6 supposed to be included in the data body? Is speed optimization crucial?

Comment: For the processing I use A B C D (i.e. row 4) as colindex. However, rows1 (general information), 2 & 3 (both empty), 4 (current colindex) 5 (i.e. units for colindex) and 6 (empty) should be in the later output file before data body starts with row 7. Speed doesn't matter...

Comment: okay, understood. see my answer for a solution. feedback appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is most likely a more neat way to do it, but it works and it only reads your data once, for performance:

(1) Read data

```
in_df = pd.read_excel("test.xls", header=0)
```

(2) create a header for later

```
header = in_df[:5]  #only first rows
```

(3) save the header columns for concat later

```
cols = list(header.columns.values) #a list with headers
```

(4) create a copy for data processing

```
data = in_df
data.rename(columns=in_df.iloc[2,:], inplace=True) # rename your columns
data = data[5:]                    # you want just the data body
data = data.reset_index(drop = True)  # reindex

#DO WHATEVER WITH DATA
```

(5) output: concat [header & data]. write output

```
data.columns = cols      # we need the old col names for concat
out_df = pd.concat([header,data])    # do the concat
out_df = out_df.reset_index(drop = True)  # reset index (if you want to)
out_df.to_csv("out.csv")   #write it. out_df.to_csv("out.csv", index = False) if you don't want index in output
```